# How to resize child objects without stretch?

Tags: lua, love2d

I want to resize the children to fit the window dependent. But currently the child is stretched when I resize the window. How to calculate right size and position without stretch objects?

My example code:

```
local objects = {
    {x = g_x + 0, y = g_y, w = 50, h = 50},
    {x = g_x + 55, y = g_y, w = 50, h = 50},
    {x = g_x + 110, y = g_y, w = 50, h = 50},
    {x = g_x + 165, y = g_y, w = 50, h = 50},
    {x = g_x + 220, y = g_y, w = 50, h = 50}
}

function love.load()
    love.window.setMode(800, 600, {resizable=true, vsync=false, minwidth=400, minheight=300})
    local n = {x = love.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 25,y = love.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - 25,w = 50,h = 50}
    table.insert(objects, n)
end

local default_w = love.graphics.getWidth()
local default_h = love.graphics.getHeight()

function love.draw()
    for i = 1, #objects do
        local obj = objects[i]
        love.graphics.setColor(42, 42, 42)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", obj.x, obj.y, obj.w, obj.h)
    end
end

function love.resize( new_w, new_h )

    local scale_Width = new_w / default_w
    local scale_Height = new_h / default_h

    for i = 1, #objects do

        local obj = objects[i]

        obj.x = obj.x * scale_Width
        obj.y = obj.y * scale_Height

        obj.w = obj.w * scale_Width
        obj.h = obj.h * scale_Height

    end

    default_w = new_w
    default_h = new_h

end
```

Without change window size : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciGoN.png
Example of my problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NevSo.png
What i want make : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wHcj.png - Blue rects was save original proportionals its what i want make but currently in my case white rects is stretched  like in second screenshot.

Comment: what is "it works very badly for me" supposed to mean? what is `default_w`? `default_h`? what is `objects`?  provide a [mcve] and ideally some screenshots of the expected and actual behaviour

Comment: @Piglet I added more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to scale position, without scaling size...
so leave these in:

```
obj.x = obj.x * scale_Width
obj.y = obj.y * scale_Height
```

but take these out:

```
obj.w = obj.w * scale_Width
obj.h = obj.h * scale_Height
```